# Get title field from another content type in exposed filter

Tags: views

I have two content types: `Project` and `Task`. `Project` has an node reference field of `Task` - when you create a `Task`, you add reference to one of Project.

I need to create a view of `Project` and add the expose filter of title of the Task. I've selected both content type like Project and Task in a filter, I can see all of the fields from the Task content type EXCEPT Title. The only `Content: Title` that's available is the one from the Project nodes.

Need help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create views of one content type ie `Project` and add a `relationship` to your views which should say something like this Task `Content referenced from Project`. Require this relationship to exclude those projects which don't have tasks.

Now come to your filters and add title. In the setting now you will see use relationship dropdown. Select the relationship you added and you will get the required results.